# Using bash to get the second word of the first line

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, sed

I am writing a simple script and need to use a bash command to get the second word of the first line. In below file, I want to only get the "host" printed out although I am having trouble doing this.

```
-bash-3.2$ cat filewithstuff
SERVERNAME      host
DOMAIN          all-nfs


-bash-3.2$ cat filewithstuff | awk  '{print $2}'
host
all-nfs
```

I was able to use the below command on the linux host:

```
cat filewithstuff | sed -n 1p | awk "{print \$1}"
```

Although when I run it from Python script, I am getting below error:

```
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cat filewithstuff | sed -n 1p | awk \"{print \\$1}\""

Aborting.

Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task 'uninstallApp'

Aborting.
```

Does not seem like my Python script likes the "\" in the bash command, does anyone know an alternative command I can try?

Comment: Where's your python code?

Comment: I don't see `python` code here

Answer (score 11):

Let awk do all the work:

```
command | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' file
```

`NR` stands for number of record (number of line here) and `$2` stands for the second field. All together, it tells awk to print the second field from the first line.

If you suspect that the output will be very large, add an `exit` to stop processing: `{print $2; exit}`.

Comment: @karakfa good one! You need a semi-colon instead of a comma, I am sure this was a typo

Answer (score 5):

Using only builtins (see, for reference, [the bash-hackers page on `read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) or [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)):

```
read -r _ secondword _ <file

echo "Second word is: $secondword"
```

...or, reading from a program's output (one can't pipe to `read` due to [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)):

```
read -r _ secondword _ < <(yourcommand)
```

The underscores here are placeholders: The first one acts as a sink for the first word, and the last one acts as a sink for the third word and any remaining, should they exist.

---

This is faster than anything involving external commands (`awk`, `head`, `cut`, etc), since it's entirely performed by the shell itself.

Answer (score 4):

In BASH:

```
head -n1 filename | cut -d' ' -f2
```

In Python:

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    print(infile.readline().split(None, 2)[1])
```

Comment: Your "bash" code is all external programs (`head`, `cut`).